# Python convert TXT to CSV

Tags: python, csv

I've been trying to convert a txt file to CSV but have been running into trouble.

My text document is in the following format:

```
POP  Issue: key=u'VPER-242', id=u'167782' 
POP  Issue: key=u'TE-8', id=u'215771' 
POP  Issue: key=u'OUTDIAL-233', id=u'223166' 
POP  Issue: key=u'OUTDIAL-232', id=u'223047'
```

The goal is to throw this into a CSV file that looks like the following with 2 columns:

```
Name of issue                         
POP  Issue: key=u'VPER-242'    
POP  Issue: key=u'TE-8'
POP  Issue: key=u'OUTDIAL-233'
POP  Issue: key=u'OUTDIAL-232'

Issue ID
id=u'167782'
id=u'215771'
id=u'223166'
id=u'223047'
```

Basically using the " , " in the txt file to act as a delimiter and separate the two into columns. The following code has worked to get the column names at the top of my CSV as well as splitting, but it is not in the right format and doesn't separate by " , ".

```
import csv
import itertools
with open('newfile1.txt', 'r') as in_file:
    stripped = (line.strip() for line in in_file)
    lines = (line for line in stripped if line)
    grouped = itertools.izip(*[lines] * 2)
    with open('newfile1.csv', 'w') as out_file:
            writer = csv.writer(out_file)
            writer.writerow(('Name of Issue', 'Issue ID'))
            writer.writerows(grouped)
```

This is what this code outputs - which is close but not quite right. I don't want spaces and need for the Issue ID column to only have the ID=u'number' data and the Name of issue to only have the POP Issue data. Anyone have any suggestions?  Thank you!

```
Name of Issue   
POP  Issue: key=u'VPER-242', id=u'167782'

POP  Issue: key=u'TE-8', id=u'215771'

POP  Issue: key=u'OUTDIAL-233', id=u'223166'


Issue ID
POP  Issue: key=u'TE-8', id=u'215771'

POP  Issue: key=u'OUTDIAL-232', id=u'223047'

POP  Issue: key=u'OUTDIAL-229', id=u'222309'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is just using itertools.izip to zip together the same array, so that is why it is printing the same result under both columns. You need to split on the comma and then move forward.

Comment: Thanks Austin - that was the section that was causing me troubles. Got it now with grouped = [line.split(',') for line in lines]

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

txt_file = r"YourTextDocument.txt"
csv_file = r"NewProcessedDoc.csv"

in_txt = csv.reader(open(txt_file, "rb"), delimiter = ',')
out_csv = csv.writer(open(csv_file, 'wb'))

out_csv.writerows(in_txt)
print 'done! go check your NewProcessedDoc.csv file'

# You can insert new rows manually in your csv for the titles (Name of issue & Issue ID)
```

Answer (score -2):

EDITED:  more details

Short answer:

Replace this:

```
grouped = itertools.izip(*[lines] * 2)
```

with this:

```
grouped = [line.split(',') for line in lines]
```

Longer answer:

Your "grouped" variable is containing pairs of duplicate lines (not what you wanted)

If your Input line doesn't contain any other comma (",") then str.split is your friend for this Mission.

Cheers

Comment: You nailed it yoav.  Thanks so much!

Comment: It won't work right if there are commas inside of the strings.

Comment: @Qwertiy - I've added your comment in the answer - Thanks!